# extends could not be found with AsyncTask android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to use AsyncTask in `class ContactsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener`, but in Xamarin give me error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbrB.png)

Could please help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance

Answer (score 0):

`extends` is not a key word in C#. In C# you would use `:` which will alter your code to:

`public class DownloadImageTask : AsyncTask<...>`